# Добавление и удаление required через jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу понять почему не работает код:

```
$('#delivery_type').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'mkad') {
        $('#cart-tk-wrapper').hide();
        $('#cart-tk-wrapper').removeAttr('required');
        $('#cart-city-wrapper').hide();
        $('#cart-city-wrapper').removeAttr('required');
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'r_post'){
        $('#cart-tk-wrapper').hide();
        $('#cart-tk-wrapper').removeAttr('required');
        $('#cart-city-wrapper').show();
        $('#city').attr('required', '')
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'tk'){
        $('#cart-city-wrapper').show();
        $('#city').attr('required', '')
        $('#cart-tk-wrapper').show();
        $('#delivery_company').attr('required', '')
    }
});
```

Во-первых вместо того, чтобы добавить required к input, почему-то добавляется required='required'. А во-вторых, после того, как атрибут добавился, он уже не удаляется, то есть removeAttr не работает. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Потому что Вы вызываете `removeAttr` не для того элемента, которому добавили этот атрибут.

Comment: блин, точно) Спасибо)